# How to output to txt (Programming in Python with Processing 3)

Tags: python, processing

I'm currently working on a project and a part of the project is to output something to the project directory in a sepereate .txt file, I have completed that but I have a problem, everything works GREAT but **I don't want to create a new file every single time but I want to have everything and all records stored in only one file and that they just keep adding up**, can someone help me?

Here's a part of the code I've came up with, don't bother about the "%d" etc. I just need help with output :

```
output = createWriter("rekordi.txt")
            output.print("Tvoj zadnji rekord je " + str(millis()/1000-sekunde) + " sekund || ob " + str(datum.strftime("%I:" + "%M" + " %p" + " na " + "%d." + "%b"))) # Write the date to the file
            output.flush()# Writes the remaining data to the file
            output.close()# Finishes the file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is open a file in `append` mode. This will create it if it doesn't exist, and will append to it instead of overwriting it if it does already exist. Something like this should do what you want:

```
my_file_path = 'output_record.txt'
with open(my_file_path, 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write(<output data here in string format> + '\n') # \n for newline
```

The `with ...` is a context manager block, which means that the file will automatically be closed when that code block exits. And the `'a'` second argument to `open` specifies `append` mode.

Hope that helps, Happy Coding (and happy Friday)!

Comment: I've tried your method and I still can't get it to work, It just keeps rewriting it over the text I have in the file, I want it to get a highscore and save it in there, and every time I open the game and play it, it saves new highscore below the last one, do you have a solution for that?

Comment: The code above works for me. One thing is that you need to append a newline `\n` if you want it to have each on its own line. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: soo if I just copy paste the code above, everything should be working? or do I have to put anything before and aftet it?

Comment: I used only the code above. I ran it several times, and saw one line for each call in my output file.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("rekordi.txt", "a", buffering=0) as f:
      f.write("write some data")
```

file mode "a" will append all data to the file
buffering=0 means that data will be written directly to the file (just like using flush() )